# Entity Framework 4.0 with Sql Compact Edition 4.0 - Not Implemented Exception

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, sql-server-ce-4

I have this LINQ query:

```
    var children = DataContext.Entities.Nodes
                    .Where(n => n.Parent.Name == node.Key)
                    .OrderBy(n => n.SortOrder);

    foreach (var child in children)
        var childNode = CreateNode(child);
```

When using SQL Server, everything works fine. However, when using SqlCe, I get the following error:

```
[SqlCeException (0x80004005): Not implemented]
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.ProcessResults(Int32 hr) +125
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.IsEndOfRowset(Int32 hr) +131
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.Move(DIRECTION direction) +376
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader.Read() +95
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +44

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +130
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +46
```

Any idea what's going on here?

I even tried calling `ToArray()` before `foreach`, but that did not help.

**EDIT:**

If I change the query to:

```
    var children = DataContext.Entities.Nodes
                    .Where(n => n.Parent.Name == node.Key)
                    .ToArray()
                    .OrderBy(n => n.SortOrder);
```

It works... why?

**EDIT 2:** BTW the `Parent` navigator points to the same table, so each `Node` can have {0..1} parent `Node`.

Comment: I was getting a similar error in my EF code, but I believe it was a deadlock exception on the transaction. I wonder if the ToArray before the OrderBy is just forcing more processing to take place in your C# code rather than in the DB, reducing the amount of processing time in the DB, and thus reducing the probability of getting a deadlock in the DB?

Comment: @deverop Did you find a solution to this or escalate to Microsoft?  I am seeing something similar without Entity Framework but it is harder to reproduce. Do you have a full example?

Comment: @Travis Nope I did not find the solution nor did I escalate. I ended up changing the query and breaking it up by calling `ToArray()` before sorting.

Comment: @adaptive Bummer.  Is the duplication scenario as simple as having a table with a parent relationship, and executing the where/orderby query above?  Or was your mapping more complex than that?

Comment: @Travis The table has to have a cyclical reference to itself. In my case, the node can have a parent as well as children of type `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the query in your Edit section works indicates that the problem is in the `OrderBy(n => n.SortOrder)` clause, because only this part of the query ...

```
DataContext.Entities.Nodes
                    .Where(n => n.Parent.Name == node.Key)
```

... is actually executed on the server. By calling `.ToArray()` you force the query to be executed and an (unsorted) list is loaded into memory. The following `OrderBy` defines a query on this list (which is an `IEnumerable` and not an `IQueryable` anymore). This second query will then be executed *in memory* on this list and EF or SqlCe is not involved in this sorting.

But generally SqlCe supports `OrderBy`, so the question remains why the first query throws an exception.

What type is `Node.SortOrder` you are trying to sort by? Is it nullable for instance or some "exotic" type which SqlCe is not able to sort by?

Comment: `Node.SortOrder` is an `int`. Might I also add that switching `OrderBy` and `Where` does not make a difference. So, `DataContext.Entites.Nodes.OrderBy(n => n.SortOrder).Where(n => n.Parent.Name == node.Key)` throws the same exception.

Comment: @deverop: Did you also test if it throws an exception if you *only sort* (`OrderBy` without `Where`) or if you *only filter* (`Where` without `OrderBy`)? This would also be interesting to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `OrderBy` by itself works, and the same applies to `Where` (as demonstrated in the question). But I just can not use them together.

Comment: @deverop: I am afraid that I don't have an idea anymore. The query you are doing looks rather simple and I can't see why it could fail. I'd recommend to ask this question also directly at Microsoft to improve your chance for a solution - for instance here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/threads/